# RSA encryption problems in android

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa

I know there are several questions on this subject, but none have answered my question, I am using the RSA encryption in android, first tried in native java and it worked very well, every time I ran I returned a different encryption but android I always get the same, and is always a bad string.

```
byte[] usernameA =  cifrador.cifra("1035861042", getAssets().open("public.key"));
byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(usernameA);  
String username = new String(encoded);
```

---

```
public byte[] cifra(Object msjO, InputStream fileNamePrivateKey) throws Exception {

    try {

        ObjectInputStream restore = new ObjectInputStream(fileNamePrivateKey);
        PublicKey llave = (PublicKey) restore.readObject();
        String msj = (String)msjO;          
        restore.close();
        if (llave != null) {

            // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            // encrypt the plain text using the public key
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, llave);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(msj.getBytes());


            return encrypted;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

In native java I do the following

```
static final String PUBLIC_KEY_FILE = "C:/keys/public.key";
inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE));
final PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) inputStream.readObject();
final byte[] cipherText = encrypt(originalText, publicKey);
```

---

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String text, PublicKey key) {

    byte[] cipherText = null;
    try {
        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        // encrypt the plain text using the public key
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly be running this on a simulator? And what do you mean by a "bad string"? What did you do to test this "bad string"? Small hint: I always make sure that I throw an `IllegalStateException("Not correctly handled yet", e)` instead of the more common `e.printStackTrace()` which isn't an exit point.

Comment: A guess: `"RSA"` resolves to an algorithm on Android, which doesn't match `ALGORITHM`. In both cases, you should specify the mode and padding (e.g. `"RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding"`). **Please can you post the value of `ALGORITHM`?**.

Comment: ok thanks, the algorithm is RSA and I'm using an emulator, the string returned by the RSA in android is not supported by the server, but the string returned by the RSA in java native is supported.

Comment: ALGORITHM = "RSA", sorry, thanks for your help

Comment: The problem is that I'm getting different results in java native and android, I need that android returns the same, because the result on android is not supported by the webservice